# What's wrong with this factorial function in clojure

Tags: clojure, factorial

I have this function:

```
(defn ! [x]
  (let [n x product 1]
    (if (zero? n)
        product
        (recur (- n 1) (* product n)))))
```

and I got error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched argument count to recur, expected: 1 args, got: 2 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:33)`

but this factorial from other SO question work fine. Why?

```
(defn fact [x]
    (loop [n x f 1]
        (if (= n 1)
            f
            (recur (dec n) (* f n)))))
```

Comment: Replace `let` with `loop`, then your `recur` will find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `recur` on `let`.

When you `recur` here, you are actually recurring on the function definition which has one argument hence `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched argument count to recur, expected: 1 args, got: 2 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:33)`.

On the second example (s)he's using `loop` which you should use when you want to `recur` on some other arguments, other than the functions.

Comment: Didn't notice that there is loop instead of let in second example. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

in your example `recur` loops to `!` which is expecting 1 param but gets 2,

in the second example `recur` loops to `loop` which is expecting 2 params and gets 2 params